# Run-time error 1004 when trying to add a conditional format to Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I ran into this in my golf gaming template when trying to customize the number of prizes to be given to each group.

I built a sample workbook with a sample problem to test the code.
The sample worked but the golf gaming template gives run-time 1004 error.

```vb
Const f1 As String = "=VLOOKUP(A1,D$1:G$10,4,FALSE)>$G$4"
Const f3 As String = "=VLOOKUP(A1,D$1:G$10,4,FALSE)=$G$4"

Public Sub modify1()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = wks.Range("C1:C10")
    Set fc = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , f3)
    fc.Interior.Color = RGB(127, 63, 63)
    fc.StopIfTrue = False
End Sub

Public Function RGB(Red As Long, Green As Long, Blue As Long) As Long
    RGB = Blue + 256 * (256 * Red + Green)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the golf workbook was protected but the sample workbook was not.
The golf workbook is protected using **UserInterfaceOnly:=True** - normally code runs fine even if it changes things in the workbook. Guess what! The conditional formatting code fails if the sheet is so protected.

Unprotecting the workbook running the code to add conditional formatting to each of three worksheets and then protecting the workbook again works, but it is a little resource intensive.

I just thought I would share this experience so others might be saved some time and aggravation if it is encountered.